# how can I insert into sql table using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

// HOW CAN I INSERT INTO SQL TABLE USING JAVASCRIPT
how can I insert  into sql table using javascript

```
        function checkout() {
```

> enter code here

`// HOW CAN I INSERT INTO SQL TABLE USING JAVASCRIPT
how can I insert  into sql table using javascript

```
        function checkout() {
          var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var method = 'GET';
          var url = 'test.php';
          var asynchronous = 'true';
          ajax.open(method, url, asynchronous);
          ajax.send();

          var customer_fname = document.getElementById('customer_fname').value;
          var customer_lname = document.getElementById('customer_lname').value;
          var customer_phone = document.getElementById('customer_phone').value;
          var area = document.getElementById('area_id').value;
          var address = document.getElementById('address_1').value;
          var order_notes = document.getElementById('order_notes').value;
          var cutting_price = document.getElementById('td_cutting_price').innerHTML;
          var wallet_price = document.getElementById('td_wallet_price').innerHTML;
          var sub_total = document.getElementById('td_sub_price').innerHTML;
          var total = document.getElementById('td_total_price').innerHTML;
          var invoice = '#' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
          var order_time = new Date();
          
          



          //receiving response from testphp
          ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


              for (var a = 0; a, data.length; a++) {
                var product_id = data[a].product_id;
                var product_size = data[a].product_size;
                var customer_email = data[a].customer_email;
                var product_title = data[a].product_title;

                // I WANT TO insert SOME OF THE ABOVE VARIABLE INTO MY pending_orders Table
              



              }


            }

          }
        }
      

      <div class="form-group mt-5">
        <a name="checkout" type="button" id="checkout" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block" style="border-color:#ec7f37;background-color: #ec7f37; color:#fff" onclick="checkout();"> Checkout</a>



      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That has to be done from the backend, you may write a script to do that with, NodeJs, PHP, Python, or Ruby. Then call the script with AJAX.

Comment: You may have to check through the codes you have in insert.php all the way to your database.

Comment: <?php 

require_once("config.php");
include('functions.php');

?>

<?php

$product_title=$_POST['product_title'];
$query=query("INSERT INTO pending_orders(product_title)VALUES('$product_title') ");
confirm($query);



?>